# Code::Blocks, не работает отладочное окно Disassembly

Tags: c, отладка, codeblocks

Проблема следующая: не могу открыть окно дизассемблирования.

Перепробовал уже все: устанавливал другие компиляторы; десятки раз переустанавливал разные версии `Code::Blocks`; прыгал с бубном вокруг настроек среды, компилятора и отладчика; выполнил любые мыслимые и немыслимые попытки получить дизассемблированный код.

Галочка на пункте `Disassembly` ставится и снимается, но при этом ничего не происходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помню, что лет пять назад это окошко без проблем открывалось, даже если отладка не запущена. Теперь же не открывается.

Помогите понять, что с этим всем делать.

Comment: А через меню Debug -> Window -> .. ? и найти окошку место в левой панели

Comment: @NewView, и это тоже пробовал. Искал окошко, нигде его нет. Раньше оно появлялось поверх остальных панелей. Сейчас так появляются все окна отладки.

Comment: Искать надо в режиме отладки, можно ещё в настройках посмотреть, может там чего выключено. У меня например работает, так что что-то в настройках, возможно сохранили настройки воркспейс без него.. как вариант

Comment: @NewView, я уже сто раз все проверил и перепроверил. Переустановил все возможные версии `Code::Blocks`, ничего не помогает. Окно дизассемблирования отказывается открываться.

Comment: А в вин реестре он ничего не хранит? может координаты этого окна за пределом видимости, и так сохранено. Или это Линукс?

Comment: @NewView, не знаю, хранит он в реестре координаты окна или нет. Как проверить - не представляю.

Comment: Поиском по реестру, вероятно, по названию codeblocks или производные от этого.

Comment: Размеры и расположение этого окна хранятся в настройках для каждого дебагера отдельно. Сами настройки CB [хранятся в файле](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=17708.0) *c:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\CodeBlocks\default.conf*. Попробуйте удалить его.

Comment: @zed, большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Помогло удаление конфига?

Comment: @zed, помогло удаление всех перспектив, которые `Code::Blocks` наплодил автоматически. Не знаю, с чем это было связано. Теперь проверить, поможет ли удаление конфига, не могу, потому что мне не удается воспроизвести пропажу окошка дизассемблера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге я выяснил, что для восстановления пропавшего отладочного окна `Disassembly` необходимо удалить все перспективы.

В моих настройках отладки был выбран пункт `Одна перспектива для каждого отладчика`. Однако, список перспектив был переполнен, и продолжал пополняться новыми пунктами, если я открывал какое-либо окно отладки или если менял определенные настройки среды/проекта.

Не знаю, должно так происходить или нет, но мне кажется, это какой-то баг.

Отключить *размножение* перспектив можно, если в настройках отладки выбрать пункт `Только одна перспектива отладки`.